# How to convert a while loop into a for loop? C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I've checked the solutions for problems that are similar to mine, but they did not work in my situation.
I want to make this program use a for loop instead of the while loop.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define SENTINEL -99

int main(void) {
  int sum = 0, number;

  printf("Enter first number (or %d to quit)> ", SENTINEL);
  scanf_s("%d", &number);
  while (number != SENTINEL) {
    sum += number;
    printf("Enter next number (%d to quit)> ", SENTINEL);
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
  }
  printf("\nThe sum of 5, 52, 31, and 65 is %d\n", sum);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: `while (<whatever>)` ==> `for( ; <whatever> ; )`

Comment: O.T.: Your code doesn't look like idiomatic C++. I cannot see anything which wouldn't be accepted by a standard C compiler but I see a lot of things which could/should be done different in C++.

Comment: Imo a `while` is the better choice here. What do you think to achieve with using a `for`-loop?

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you know that the user will input `5, 52, 31, and 65`? ;-)

Comment: Personally, I'd improve the structure of the `while` loop and eliminate duplication of code (e.g.  prompting the user and reading input in two distinct places) before even *considering* turning the `while` loop into a `for` loop.   But, generally speaking, you can't expect too many answers here - generally, the only time someone has an explicit request to turn a `while` loop into some other loop, it is a homework exercise - and anyone with experience knows that you will learn more by working out how to do it for yourself than by begging and being spoon-fed solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#define SENTINEL -99

int 
main(void)
{
int sum = 0, number;
    std::vector<int> v;
    
printf("Enter first number (or %d to quit)> ", SENTINEL);
scanf_s("%d", &number);
for(int i = 0; number != SENTINEL; i++) {
    sum += number;
    v.push_back(number);
    printf("Enter next number (%d to quit)> ", SENTINEL);
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
}
    for(int n : v) {
        printf("%d, ", n);
    }
printf(" = %d\n", sum);
return (0);
}
```

You used the C++ tag, but your code uses the C library.

You can compile with a parameter like this:
`g++ code.cpp`

Comment: Why do you introduce an unused variable `int i = 0`?

Comment: @mch The user may want to know how many times the loop has run. I think this will be necessary for his other statements.